# How calculate penalty fee with dueDate variable in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the penalty fee when someone submits a book after the due date. It should charge a certain amount of money per each day and stop charging once the person has paid back the amount in total. I want to read the due date from a table in my database and calculate the penalty fee accordingly. when I run the code, the Amount due column produces these error messages : 
"**Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object**" and "***Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function FeesCalc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\phplms\librarian\return_book.php:119 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown***"

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
    $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from issue_book where student_enrollment='$_POST[enr]' ");
    echo "<table class = 'table table-bordered'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>"; echo "student enrollement"; echo "</th>";
    echo "<th>"; echo "student name"; echo "</th>";
    echo "<th>"; echo "Amount Due"; echo "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>"; echo $row["student_enrollment"]; echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; echo $row["student_name"]; echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; ?><?php 
    $a = mysqli_query($link, "select due_date from issue_book where student_enrollment='$_POST[enr]' ");
    $due = date("Y/m/d",strtotime($a));
    $TodayDate = strtotime('today');

    $timeDiff = abs($TodayDate - strtotime($due));

    $numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day

    $numberDays = intval($numberDays);

    $noOfdaysToCheck ="6";

    $Fees ="0";

    if ($numberDays >= $noOfdaysToCheck){

     $Interval = $numberDays%$noOfdaysToCheck;

    for($i=1;$i<=$Interval;$i++){
     $late = "5";
    $Fees =  FeesCalc($Fees);

    }
    }

    $Fees = number_format($Fees, 2, '.', '');
    echo $Fees;

    function FeesCalc($Fees){
    $late = "5";
    return $TotalFees = $late+$Fees;

    }
    ?><?php  echo "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: if ($numberDays <= $noOfdaysToCheck)---at this line, if I put >= it shows 0 and not sure if that is the correct answer because it has to start counting from the first day of issuing to a certain number of day and then start charging a penalty on each day

Comment: I do realize you're new to Stack Overflow, but you have to realize that your question gets the most attention in the first 15 minutes after submitting it. It's been half an hour since you were asked what the problem with the code is, and you haven't responded. That makes it unlikely that you will actually get some help.

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know, really appreciate it. Well, can you help me out if you can

Comment: No, I cannot help you. It is unclear what you want help with.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have tried to edit the code, I hope this is a much better explanation.

Comment: This is basic debugging. 1. You should check what the result of the query is, before giving it to `strtotime()`, start with a simple: `echo "[$a]";` and see what it says. 2. Put `function FeesCalc() { ... }` at the beginning of your script, before `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`.